# javamail ignoring socks proxy

Tags: proxy, jakarta-mail, socks

I've setup javamail to run through a socks proxy, but it won't go through it.  I tried setting both mail.smtp.socks.host and mail.smtp.socks.port but it keeps going direct to the mail host.  I feel like I'm missing something very basic.  any help would be appreciated.  Here's my properties:

```java
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", this.smtpHost);
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", Integer.toString(this.smtpPort));
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", this.smtpUser);
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", Boolean.toString(this.smtpTLS));
props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");

if (this.useSOCKSProxy) {
   logger.info("Using proxy");
   props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socks.host", "127.0.0.1");
   props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socks.port", Integer.toString(1080));
   props.setProperty("mail.smtps.socks.host", this.socksProxyHost);
   props.setProperty("mail.smtps.socks.port", Integer.toString(this.socksProxyPort));
   props.setProperty("proxySet", "true");
   props.setProperty("socksProxyHost", this.socksProxyHost);
   props.setProperty("socksProxyPort", Integer.toString(this.socksProxyPort));
}

 //Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new SmtpAuthenticator(this.smtpUser,this.smtpPassword));
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
   new Authenticator() {
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
         return new PasswordAuthentication(smtpUser, smtpPassword);
      }
   });

 //Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
session.setDebugOut(System.out);
session.setDebug(true);
 //Transport tr = session.getTransport("smtp");
 //tr.connect();
 //tr.connect(this.smtpHost,this.smtpPort, this.smtpUser, this.smtpPassword);

Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(this.smtpFrom));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setText(msgToSend.toString());
msg.saveChanges();

Transport.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by fixing these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

If that doesn't solve the problem, post the debugging output.  Set the System property "mail.socket.debug" to "true" to get additional debugging output.

What version of JavaMail are you using?  What JDK?

Unless "props" is coming from System.getProperties(), setting "socksProxyHost" has no effect.  And if you do set it as a System property, you don't need the JavaMail socks properties.

Comment: It turns out the problem was the common pebkac.  I was running javamail 1.4.2, not 1.4.5.  Setting the system mail.socket.debug was very helpful.

Comment: @mlbiam This should not be accepted as answer. Upvoted for usefulness, yes, but it doesn't answer your question!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to figure out the correct combination of properties, including the common mistakes Bill mentioned, or you can also go the easy way and let [Simple Java Mail](http://www.simplejavamail.org) (open source) figure it out for you:

Your example converted:

```java
Mailer mailer = new Mailer(
        new ServerConfig(smtpHost, smtpPort, smtpUser, smtpPassword),
        TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS,
        this.useSOCKSProxy ? new ProxyConfig(socksProxyHost, socksProxyPort) : null
);

mailer.setDebug(true);

mailer.sendMail(new EmailBuilder()
        .from(null, smtpForm)
        .to(null, email)
        .subject(subject)
        .text(msgToSend.toString())
        .build());
```

Note how you don't have to deal with any properties or JavaMail API anymore. You can also use authenticated proxy if you need.